# Can I use shell wildcards to select filenames ranging across double-digit numbers (e.g., from foo_1.jpg to foo_54.jpg)?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I have a directory with image files `foo_0.jpg` to `foo_99.jpg`.  I would like to copy files `foo_0.jpg` through `foo_54.jpg`.

Is this possible just using bash wildcards?

I am thinking something like `cp foo_[0-54].jpg` but I know this selects `0-5` and `4` (right?)

Also, if it is not possible (or efficient) with just wildcards what would be a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I assume you want to copy these files to another directory:

```
cp -t target_directory foo_{0..54}.jpg
```

Comment: +1: Like the use of the {0..54}. That's much cleaner than the globbing

Comment: You are amazing!  Would you happen to know where in the bash manual that is described?  I can't find it but I now remember seeing it somewhere.  Nevermind.  Found it under Brace Expansion.

Comment: Apparently this brace expansion sequence expression is used for file name matching but not for regex.

Answer (score 10):

I like [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) answer, but if you really want to use globbing, following might also work for you:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cp foo_+([0-9]).jpg $targetDir
```

In extended globbing `+()` matches one or more instances of whatever expression is in the parentheses.

Now, this will copy ALL files that are named `foo_` followed by any number, followed by `.jpg`. This will include `foo_55.jpg`, `foo_139.jpg`, and `foo_1223218213123981237987.jpg`.

On second thought, glenn jackman has the better answer. But, it did give me a chance to talk about [extended globbing](http://aplawrence.com/Words2005/2005_05_25.html).

Answer (score 4):

ls foo_[0-9].jpg foo_[1-4][0-9].jpg foo_5[0-4].jpg

Try it with ls and if that looks good to you then do the copy.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: That's good except it will match files like foo_a.jpg if they exist.  Perhaps replacing your ?'s with [0-9]'s is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in `seq 0 54`; do cp foo_$i.jpg <target>; done
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension answer of @grok12's answer above

```bash
$ ls foo_([0-9]|[0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]).jpg
```

Basically the regex above will match below

- anything with a single digit OR
- two digits and that first digit must be between 0-4 and second digit between 0-9 OR
- two digits and that first digit is 5 and second digit between 0-9

Alternatively you can achieve similar result with regex below

```bash
$ ls file{[0-9],[0-4][0-9],5[0-4]}.txt
```