# Copy a range of folders in command line

Tags: linux, bash

I found this link with an example of how I can actually copy range of files https://serverfault.com/questions/370403/copy-a-range-of-files-in-command-line-zsh-bash, using this

```
$cp P10802[75-83].JPG ~/Images/.
```

Is there any way I can also copy range of folders or directory?

Maybe something like this `$cp -r folder[001-999] ~/images./`

Comment: wait, are you using the **wrong** command from the question, or the **correct** command from one of the answers?!

Comment: Is cp [OPTION]... SOURCE DEST  not the right command?

Comment: maybe a better example of what you are trying to copy?

Comment: Yes, @user123451, that is the right command, but the brackets `[]` are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-R` flag to recursive copy the directories. According to [Can I use shell wildcards to select filenames ranging across double-digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443756/369450), you can use the syntax `{start..end}` to match a number range. Putting that together would give you:

```
cp -R folder{001..999} ~/images./
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the same logic. Globbing and expansion (which is what bash uses to generate the individual names out of these patterns) work on files as well as on directory names.

Comment: Yes, but this worked as files only when i tried it, i didn't work for folders

Comment: Then you have a typo or are not using the right command. Bash doesn't make a difference between names that point to directories and names that point to files.